# Progress bar loader on splash screen for phonegap android and iphone application

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have started working on an app using phonegap 2.9.1, before my app loads there will be splash screens sliding automatically from left to right and above the splash screen there will be a progress bar loader, it will continue until index.html page loads.I am stuck at his for longer time. Provide me a good solution for this.Right now only a splash image is showing up.Please help me out.The code in main.java

```
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.setStringProperty("loadingDialog", "Wait,Loading Demo...");
    super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(), 10000);
   //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

@Namrata,

1. Phonegap 2.9.1 is not supported.
2. you are writing a plugin

read [Plugin Development Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html)

Best of Luck